# Cannot create datastore Starwind from powercli

Tags: powercli

In vmware 6.7 i want create starwind datastore (iSCSI) with powercli. I tried some script like this:

```
Get-VMHost 192.168.10.210 | get-scsilun | where vendor -like "Starwind"
$SCSIID = Get-VMHost 192.168.10.210 | get-scsilun | where vendor -Like "Starwind" 
$SCSIID = $SCSIID.CanonicalName
New-Datastore -VMHost 192.168.10.210 -Name "VolumeName" -Path $SCSIID
```

but i receive always the same error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gNfr.png)

May you help me?

Comment: You may want to check the value of your `$scsiid` variable to ensure that it still contains appropriate information.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree - most likely you have a problem with you $SCSIID variable. I have tested your code on my starwind setup and it works. Since you have only one device, you do not need to specify CanonicalName property. You can simply do:

```
Get-VMHost 192.168.10.210 | get-scsilun | where vendor -like "Starwind"
$SCSIID = Get-VMHost 192.168.10.210 | get-scsilun | where vendor -Like "Starwind" 
New-Datastore -VMHost 192.168.10.210 -Name "VolumeName" -Path $SCSIID
```

Alternatively, you can simply filter block device by CanonicalName and create datastore. That's how I have done it:

```
$SCSIID = Get-VMHost 192.168.10.210 | get-scsilun | where -eq "eui.ca647c38f8e985f7"
New-Datastore -VMHost 192.168.10.210 -Name "VolumeName" -Path $SCSIID
```

FYI, I am posting StarWind related questions on their forum.
https://forums.starwindsoftware.com/